# Facing an error when trying to redirect using middleware in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I want to redirect the user when there is no token. Basically, the token is removed automatically if it has expired. At that time, if I want to send a request to any server action, I face an error. The error is

```
TypeError: __webpack_modules__[moduleId] is not a function
    at Object.__webpack_require__ [as require
```

The middleware code is

```
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value;
  const currPath = request.nextUrl.pathname;

  if (!token && currPath !== "/login") {
    console.log("Error");
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
  } else if (token && currPath === "/login") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/admin/appointment", request.url));
  }
}
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/admin/:path*", "/login"],
};
```

In console showing this error
[image]

Can anyone help me solve this error? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the error as a text, not an image.

Comment: I think the error is in `/login` route, not inside the middleware.